# Set of all points $(x,x-1)$ where $x \in \mathbb{Q}$ is countable

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, algebra-precalculus

I am able to see that the set of all points $(x,x-1)$ where $x \in \mathbb{Q}$ is countable since it is a subset of $\mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q}$.

But I am finding difficulty in finding a one-one function from the set to $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Can you show that $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable? Use that.

Comment: "But I am finding difficulty in finding a one-one function from the set to N." Why do you need to?  $f: \{(x,x-1)| x\in \mathbb Q\} \to \mathbb Q$ via $f(w, w-1) = w$ is clearly a bijection so the set is countable.  No need to find an bijection to $\mathbb N$.  But if you have a bijection from $\phi: \mathbb Q\to \mathbb N$ then just use $\phi\circ f(x,x-1) = \phi (x)$ is the bijection if you need it.

Answer (score 2):

Since $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable, take any bijection $f: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{Q}$. Then $g(x) = (f(x), f(x) - 1)$ is a bijection.

Answer (score 0):

There's a trivial bijection with  $\mathbb Q $.